# Как выложить проект Nuxt.js на статическом хостинге?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

Можно ли на виртуальном хостинге раз проект на Nuxt.js? Сделал npm run generate (развёртывание для стат. Хоста), и ничего не работает В документации об этом всего пару строк и никакой информации. 
Как быть и что делать ???

Comment: Читали описание? `Nuxt.js — это минималистичный фреймворк для создания приложений на Vue.js с серверным рендерингом`. Ответ: нет. `npm run generate` скорее всего имелось в виду что вы "на нормальном" билдите, а затем полученные файлы переносите копированием

Comment: Собираюсь взять VPS:
- Чистый сервер
- СеnrtOS7 (там такое же использование npm как на windows?)
-1/2 CPU, 512 MB RAM, 15 GB SSD

Скажите, достаточно ли будет такого хостинга для развёртывания Nuxt.js?

Comment: Достаточно. Возьмите по памяти 1-2 Гб, если будет база данных, цена вопроса 250 руб/мес. Ну а для билдежки файлов такого объема достаточно. npm работает также.